# Why Does My PMG Generator gets Locked Up?

Tags: power, generator

I tired to connect a 60 W 240 V resistive load to a 1000 W generator which was running at 200 V immediately after the load was connected the voltage drops to 60 V and the generator stops spinning. By the way it is a three phase 415 V delta generator.

Comment: What was turning the generator? Power out = power in minus losses

Comment: Im using wind to turn the generator. As the voltage generated reaches a 180 V i tired to hook up a 10 W load. The rotor start to slow down so drastically till it literally stop spinning.

Comment: How large a diameter WT?. What wind velocity? What did the 10W load consist of. eg a 10W light bulb may book like a 100W+ load until properly lit. | Power ~= 600 x A x V^3 x efficiency Watts. A m^2. V m^3. Efficiency 5%-40% deep-ending on design.

Comment: It's only a 1000 watt generator if there is 1000 watts (plus mechanical losses and electrical losses) mechanical power turning the rotor.

Comment: Lots of good info on making wind turbines here http://scoraigwind.co.uk/ If your blades are less than 2.5m dia, they are probably too small to drive a 1kw generator.

Comment: sorry for the late replies guys, here is the deal. I'm dealing with a constant wind speed of 20 m/s. It is coming out from my ducting system that I have installed from the exhaust of the tester. Like wise the natural wind turbine requires massive blades to capture as much wind as possible mine would just need a good size blade just to rotate the generator. Rated is 1000 W but max is 1500 W. @RussellMcMahon.

Comment: 20m/s. That's fast! What is your rotor diameter. When you plug it into the above formular what power do you get? What rotor are you using? - proper 'profiles (NACA xxx or ...) or ??? | NBNBNB - 10 Watts under what conditions- 12vbulb, 230 V bulb, ...???

Comment: Whoops: Formula should be Watts = 600 x A x V^3/1000 zx Z. (0 < Z < 0.59 = efficiency). At 20 m/S and 10 W and 10% Z you need  only about 160mm dia rotor to make 10 Watts. | Answer above questions for an answer.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon basic wind formulae would work, as it calculates swipe area of the rotor. My 20 m/s wind is from a ducting not from an open air. Thus my concept more towards hydro turbine concept.

Comment: @Sarenya (1) My formula IS basic wind formula - presented in a minimalist and usable form. (2) You want answers but seem to resist providing the minimum information required to make useful sense of your question. (3) The formula I have effectively provides the energy available in an air stream whether ducted or not. The 0.59 max value I have for Z is the Betz upper efficiency limit which does not apply to ducted systems if the rotor is unable to be bypassed by airflow - but you'd need a far better rotor Z than almost any to exceed 60% efficiency. My formula incorporates a fluid density of ....

Comment: ... about 1.2 kg/m^3 - ie air at sea level at 25 degrees C. If you are using air and not water or mercury etc then my formula is "in the order of right". Why not answer a few simple questions to see if it helps us help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the PMG getting locked:

(1) My wind Source is not strong enough. Needs a proper channeling to the blade. May be a reverse blower concept might be implemented.

(2) My Blade Design is needed to be improvised. Blower Fan is too heavy and not effecient enough.

Reasons:
Tried to hook up a 60 W load and use extra force on the blade, by means of rotating it by hand. The light starts to turn ON. Concludes that at current state the blades requires additional torque in load condition. At no load it is generation 270 V 30 Hz, I would need to push up the no load condition up to 415 V 50 Hz then only try to load the generator and see.

Comment: You gave us a windspeed but not a ducting diameter. Given both, we can get the max power available (before turbine and generator losses)

Comment: @BrianDrummond the diameter of ducting is not finalized yet as we haven't implement the reducer yet so far the ducting end is 1ft by 1ft and the wind speed is 20 m/s.

Comment: Near enough. Cross sectional area <0.1m^2 and 20m/s gives 2m^3/s air volume or 2.4kg/s. So there's <480W in the airflow to begin with.